# Convert Json hash in CSV to ruby hash

Tags: json, csv, hash, ruby-2.4

In CSV file, I have the following line :

```
data1;data2;{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

I can parse it and get my ruby hash like this :

```
require 'csv'
line = 'data1;data2;{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
csv = CSV.parse_line(line, col_sep: ";", quote_char: "\x00")
=> ["data1", "data2", "{\"key1\":\"val", "ue1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"]
JSON.parse(csv[2])
```

But... it fails when a value includes seperator character (`;`), because it is interpreted

```
require 'csv'
line = 'data1;data2;{"key1":"val;ue1","key2":"value2"}'
csv = CSV.parse_line(line, col_sep: ";", quote_char: "\x00")
=> ["data1", "data2", "{\"key1\":\"val", "ue1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"]
# Of course
JSON.parse(csv[2])
JSON::ParserError: 784: unexpected token at '{"key1":"val'
```

Any idea how to deal with it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct syntax using CSV to write my hash. Change hash in csv file from

```
data1;data2;{"key1":"val;ue1","key2":"value2"}
```

to

```
data1;data2;"{""key1"":""val;ue1"",""key2"":""value2""}"
```

This is not really human readable, but it works.

Full working code :

```
require 'csv'
line = 'data1;data2;"{""key1"":""val;ue1"",""key2"":""value2""}"'
csv = CSV.parse_line(line, col_sep: ";", quote_char: "\"")
=> ["data1", "data2", "{\"key1\":\"val;ue1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"]
JSON.parse(csv[2])
=> {"key1"=>"val;ue1", "key2"=>"value2"}
```